# Printing multiple lines of output with the CMD shell (Python)

Tags: python, shell, output

I have a simple question today.  Basically, I want to print 2 or more lines of output in the CMD shell with python.  Here is an example:

Regular CMD Shell:

```
Output
```

What I want:

```
Output
Output1
Ect.
```

I'm using Python 3.x fyi.  I don't even know if this is possible with typical Python libraries, thanks for your answers!

Edit: Due to confusion, I've dedcided to write more in detail.  I'd like to have 2 or more live outputs while a loop or something of the matter is running.  So, for example, if I was running a clock in a `while True` loop, I could use the carriage return function and have 2 outputs running.

Edit #2: So I'm going to give you guys a situation in which I would need an answer to this question.  Basically, I made a loop that displays the current time and the time until 7:30 pm to the CMD shell using a return so it all stays neatly on one line.  However, I need it so instead of me printing all the information I need on 1 line, it does it on 2.  Here is the output:

```
Time:  12:44:38 Time Left Until 7:30:  6:45:22
```

What I want it to be:

```
Time:  12:44:38 
Time Left Until 7:30:  6:45:22
```

Here is my code:

```
import datetime
import time
import sys
while True:
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    end_time = ('19:30:00')
    total_time=(datetime.datetime.strptime(end_time,'%H:%M:%S') - datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time,'%H:%M:%S'))

    print ('Time: ', start_time, 'Time Left Until 7:30: ', total_time, end='\r')

    time.sleep(0.1)
```

When I try to print anything below the carriage return, it doesn't print and when I put the carriage return in the second print, the original loop prints down and not in one line.  Thanks again!

Comment: Just outputting didn't work?

Comment: If you just want to print to standard output, use the print() function

Comment: @AllenMoh I know that, but I want to live outputs printing at the same time

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `cls` command blinks, you can use ANSI commands to control. First you have to enable ANSI in the windows cmd. You can use a 3rd party library such as `colorama` to do that.

Once you've enabled ANSI, you can use it to move up a line and delete a line (and also add nice colors ).

```
 colorama.init() # don't forget to call
```

Up a line: `sys.stout.write('\033[1A')`

Delete current line: `sys.stout.write(' \r\033[K')`

Answer (score 1):

You can refresh the cmd window by calling `os.system('cls')`. This will clear the screen and allow you to print your updated output.

Comment: Use the cls command to clear the whole screen and print your line normally, without the carriage return